# alternatives to frames to include content from different servers

Tags: html, iframe, frame, frames, dropbox

I need to make a series of webpages. Each with a header coming from a website, and the content coming from an html page in my dropbox/public. I simple way would be to use frames, but they are deprecated.

As the html content is of different size. So the iFrame does not seem to be the right tool.

What alternatives do I have?

Many people seemed to suggest in the comments ajax with jsonp. Unfortunately I am completely new to those methods, so I would need an example to copy and then work with.

Thanks,
Pietro

Comment: jquery+ajax could do the magic in the simplest way.

Comment: interesting, can you expand your suggestion in a full fledged answer with code that I can test, vote and in case accept?

Comment: Are the websites you want to pull from in your domain? If not, the only HTML way to do this that I know of is iframes. Check out this article: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj.

If they are on your domain, check out jquery ajax $.load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: They are on my public dropbox, as such they are out of my domain. Thanks for the link.

Comment: AJAX, JSONP and a callback function would do the trick nicely.

Comment: Thanks. Again I would need some code to test this solution. I don't really know much about jsonp and ajax

Comment: Just make the iFrame as big as the available space underneath the header. If the content is bigger than this iFrame the iframe will show a scrollbar. The only downside is that the header stays on the top when scrolling down, but some people find this a feature.

Comment: Gerben, iframes are terrible in this context. Simply because the size of the iframes is fixed. And it will not change with the content nor with with the size of the browser. It's like having something stuck when everything else is fluid. Aaargh! If this is what I need to do I would be much better off with normal frames.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the Jquery library in the main page. Copy the above code on the header of your page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The make a div with the `response` id:

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

JQuery has an AJAX function called "load", this function is appended to a selector where you want a page to be loaded, in this case we want to contents of file "exemple.html" to load in the tag with id "response".

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    // load exemple page when the page loads
    $("#response").load("exemple.html");
});

</script>
```

Also you can load the content when a link from the main page is clicked:

```
<script>

$("#exemple").click(function(){
    // load exemple page on click
        $("#response").load("exemple.html");
    });

</script>
```

For this you have to add on your HTML code a link with the `id="exemple"`

```
<a href="#" id="exemple">Click to load the exemple page</a>
```

Hope this helps you!